# How to paginate this loop?

Tags: php, foreach

I want to paginate the members list, but I don't know how

```php
<?php
    $users = get_users();
    echo '<div class="box-list">';
    foreach( $users as $user ) {
        echo '<div class="user-list"><div class="list-av">';
        echo get_avatar( $user->ID, 200 ). '</div><div class="list-ten">';
        $udata = get_userdata( $user->ID );$registered = $udata->user_registered;
        printf('<b>%s</b> %s<br>', $udata->data->display_name,date( "d/m/Y", strtotime( $registered ) ) ); echo '</div></div>';}  
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can splice the users array: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php

```
$page = 1;
$users_per_page = 10;
$users_on_this_page = array_splice( $users, (($page-1)*$users_per_page), $users_per_page);
```

Then loop on $users_on_this_page

```
foreach($users_on_this_page as $user){
//your code
}
```